# Check if file is CSV code is working with error

Tags: php, csv, eof

I found this code on Internet changed according to my requirements first time using EOF. I don't understand why it is showing an error.
Undefined variable: content on line 70!!! I know it is undefined but I don't know how to fix it.

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD',"");
define('DB_NAME', 'uploadcsv');

@$conn = mysql_connect (DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db (DB_NAME,$conn);
if(!$conn){
    die( "Sorry! There seems to be a problem connecting to our database.");
}

function get_file_extension($file_name) {
    return end(explode('.',$file_name));
}
 $error="";
function errors($error){
    if (!empty($error))
    {
            $i = 0;
            $showError="";
            while ($i < count($error)){
            $showError.= '<div class="msg-error">'.$error[$i].'</div>';
            $i ++;}
            return $showError;
    }// close if empty errors
} // close function


if (isset($_POST['upfile'])){
// check feilds are not empty

if(get_file_extension($_FILES["uploaded"]["name"])!= 'csv')
{
$error[] = 'Only CSV files accepted!';
}

if (!$error){

$tot = 0;
$handle = fopen($_FILES["uploaded"]["tmp_name"], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    for ($c=0; $c < 1; $c++) {


            if($data[0] !='keywords'){
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO fields(
                keywords,
                tags
                )VALUES(
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."',
                    '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."'
                )")or die(mysql_error());
            }

    $tot++;}
}
fclose($handle);
$content.= "<div class='success' id='message'> CSV File Imported, $tot records added </div>";

}// end no error
}//close if isset upfile 
$er = errors($error);
$content.= <<<EOF
<h3>Import CSV Data</h3>
$er
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    File:<input name="uploaded" type="file" maxlength="20" /><input type="submit" name="upfile" value="Upload File">
</form>
EOF;
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and will not work anymore. Use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `MySQLi` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: no even its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn't create the variable. The first usage of `$content` is you adding string parts to it.

So at line `59`

```
$content.= "<div class='success' id='message'> CSV File Imported, $tot records added </div>";
```

Removing the `.` before the `=` should make the variable work, since you're creating it, not attempting to concatenate it.

```
$content= "<div class='success' id='message'> CSV File Imported, $tot records added </div>";
```

Comment: Hey actually its partially working.. I changed $content. with $content wherever it was in code and code is working fine. But previously if i added 15 fields it used to me a message 15 fields added and now no message is getting displayed

Comment: `$content =` changes the string value, `$content .=` will add more text to the actual string.